# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ppr')

Tags: next.js

I get this Server Error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ppr')
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

I was trying to make a copy of a famous movie streaming site.

```
import React from 'react'

import Movies from "@/mocks/movies.json";
import Genres from "@/mocks/genres.json";

import FeauturedMovie from '@/components/feautured-movie';
import Categories from '@/components/categories';

function HomeContainer() {
  return (
    <div>
      <FeauturedMovie movie={Movies.results[0]}/>
      <Categories categories={Genres.genres.slice(0,5)}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default HomeContainer
```

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { FaPlus } from "react-icons/fa";

import styles from "./styles.module.css";

function FeaturedMovie({ movie = {}, isCompact = true }) {
  const { poster_path, title, overview } = movie;

  return (
    <div className={styles.movieWrapper}>
      <h1 className={styles.movieTitle}>{title}</h1>
      <p
        className={`${styles.overview} ${
          isCompact ? styles.shortOverview : ""
        }`}
      >
        {overview}
      </p>
      <div className={styles.actionButtons}>
        <Link className={styles.playButton} href={`/movie/${movie.id}`}>
          Play
        </Link>
        <button className={styles.addButton}>
          <FaPlus />
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.moviePoster}>
        <div className={styles.moviePosterOverlay}></div>
        <Image
          unoptimized
          src={`https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original${poster_path}`}
          alt={title}
          fill
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


export { FeaturedMovie };
```

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

import styles from "./styles.module.css";

function Categories({ categories }) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.categories}>
      {categories.map((category) => (
        <Link
          key={category.id}
          className={styles.category}
          href={`/${category.id}`}
        >
          <div className={styles.name}>{category.name}</div>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export { Categories };
```

I expected site to work proper but it come up with this error.

Comment: The error mentions `ppr` but no code with `ppr` included. I think the error comes from somewhere else

Comment: I'm also having the same issue after I upgraded nextjs to 14.0.2. I downgraded it to 14.0.1 and it started working again.